# GPU for smooth 1080p on 250 watt PC

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, graphics-card, power-supply

How do I upgrade my GX280 so it can play smooth 1080p video smoothly when displaying full screen?  I have a Dell Optiplex GX280.

Keeping in mind that it only has a 250 wall PSU.

Comment: From FAQ: "**Not about** a shopping or buying recommendation"

Comment: If I did want shopping recommendations, where would I ask at stackexchange?

Comment: This could easily be edited to simply ask "How do I upgrade my 250W PC to play 1080p smoothly fullscreen?", at which point it loses much of the shopping/buying recommendation elements. The answers so far seem to be following this generalisation anyway, so I'd recommend this @oshirowanen to make the question more acceptable but also to improve the chances of getting a working solution (because you widen the scope at the same time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically for this kind of power supply and low profile PC (assuming it is NOT a shopping question, but asking how you can play back fullHD content on a low-profile, not-so-strong PC), you need a GeForce card. NVidia Geforce. Why? Because it comes with VDPAU.

You can play all the HD content on Linux if the card comes with VDPAU.
See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_PureVideo) whether the card you look at have the neccessary feature. The higher version VP, the more it can decode. A **VP4** card would be the best.

[About VDPAU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU).

Comment: I don't need a card for gaming, the computer is good enough for me, I just need it for smooth 1080p video playback at full screen.

Answer (score 0):

'Smooth' 1080p playback isn't so much a function of the video card as a function of how fast the computer can decode the video and create a framebuffer for display to the video device.  More powerful GPUs increase the speed of 3D gaming more than 2D video playback.  A fast, expensive GPU on a slow computer will still render the video slowly.

If you want it for gaming, then the more graphics memory for texture caches the better.

Comment: You can offload the decoding to the GPU

Comment: I don't need a card for gaming, the computer is good enough for me, I just need it for smooth 1080p video playback at full screen.